# How to retrieve data from MySQL database in Django and display it in html page?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL database and display it in a html page using python.

Here is my view.py:

```
def show(request):
    data = Persons.objects.all()

    person = {
       "Persons": data
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", person)
```

models.py:

```
class Persons(models.Model):   
   PersonID = models.IntegerField()
   LastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   City = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   class Meta:
      db_table = "persons"
```

html:

```
  <div>
      {% for item in Person %}
          <div class="numbers">{{ item.LastName }}</div>
       {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

But I didnot retrieve anything.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a dict key `Persons`

```
person = {
   "Persons": data
}
```

...but you iterate over `Person`

```
{% for item in Person %}
```

Comment: If I am iterating over Persons I am getting error Table 'mysql.persons' doesn't exist"

Comment: That's the table you specified in your Model `db_table = "persons"`. Does the table exist?

Comment: Yes, the table exists is MySQL database.

Comment: To debug, use the Django shell to access the table. `./manage.py shell`. Then import your `Persons` Model and try to read from it. If that still doesn't work, the bug is probably in you database settings.